How to identify which rpm database is being queried?
Good morning,
I have an internal tool that does some requirements checks prior to deploy our software. One of these checks is to check for mandatory packages installed or not.
When the client executes the checks it highlitghs that some packages are missing (example compat-openssl10) but the client told me it's because with their login, rpm is querying another database that does not contain it (developers software is deployed through rpm and maybe they don't want to mess the default rpm database).
If the client execute rpm -q with the default database then it's available.
i looked at the rpm man pages and my understanding is that rpm configuration can use different config file and potentially different databases. Question: is my understanding correct?
Then how can I identify which database is being queried when i execute rpm -q?
Thanks for reading.

It seems that they've been using a different  database to install the packages. --dbpath DIRECTOR  as from the man page should be used if you want to query another database for the rpm's.

Thanks @ValentinBajrami, looking at the output of  rpm --showrc I could spot the parameter -13: _dbpath /opt/xx/devxx/rpmdb. Using rpm --dbpath xxx solved the issue

Great. So please answer your own question so this way you can help others solve the problem if they encounter such.

rpm --showrc output shows the rpmdb being queried.
Example:
-13: _dbpath   /opt/xxx/yyy/rpmdb
Using rpm --dbpath xxx allowd to query a different rpmdb
